# Would it be appropriate to reopen the "'Home page' or 'homepage'" question from seven years ago?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The question ["Home page" or "homepage"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112038/home-page-or-homepage) was closed seven years ago on the following grounds:

> This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.

However, a perusal of Hugo's carefully researched answer to the question indicates that the answer is by no means "definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source." To the contrary, readers who go to merriam-webster.com or to the link provided beneath the posted question by one of the close voters for a definitive and permanent answer will encounter a fundamentally misleading answer to the question—an answer that treats "home page" as the only legitimate spelling.

A tangential issue here is whether the question is of enduring interest to site visitors. In that regard  I note that, despite its having been closed for the past seven years, the question has been viewed more than 51,000 times by visitors to EL&U. Clearly, a lot of people are interested in an informed answer to this question.

In my view, Hugo's answer is extremely useful and is a model of the kind of effort that makes English Language & Usage a valuable online resource. It is certainly more useful and valuable than any fifty open single-word request questions and answers selected at random from the pages of EL&U. Please consider voting to reopen this question.

Comment: Questions about the spelling of words as a single word,  two words or hyphenated words are probably the most recurring on ELU and as consequence they are often closed as duplicates. I wonder if the question you mention is the original one of the long series.  The answers are definitely   worth visibility on this site.

Comment: I just now voted to reopen.  It was a reasonable question, with a well researched answer.   Aside from what Sven said above, questions with rich answers should not be closed, in my opinion, simply because a Google search can quickly turn up a short, oversimplified answer.  If a C question elicits an A answer, the site is enriched.  Of course, better to also improve the question, but the best is the enemy of the good.

Comment: I have fixed the link in the comment

Comment: @Matt E. Эллен: Thanks for updating that link. I have altered the relevant portion of my posted question to address the linked dictionary's treatment of 'home page'/'homepage'.

Comment: Yay! It's reopened!